# Java - While Loop Conditional Statement Failure With int Values

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, int

In Java programming, I'm trying to put an int through a while loop, and I want the int to be less than nine and greater than zero. But when the program runs, it only registers the first condition (in this case, "num<1") and ignores the second ("num>9").

```
int num = console.nextInt();
while(num<1 && num>9){
    System.out.println("You must type a number less than nine and greater than zero to continue.");
    num = console.nextInt();
}
```

I've flipped their order, and the same issue shows up. Why is the program registering the first condition in the while loop but not the second? I've never had this problem with Strings, are ints formatted differently in this situation?

Comment: First of all why, why are you checking if num>9 AND num<1? That's impossible and will never reach the code. To check if either conditions are true, use || as in an OR operator

Answer (score 1):

As of my understanding it is same in  most of the programming languages.

The reason is `a && b` means if `a` is true and `b` is true then only over all condition will becomes true.So if 'a' is not true then there is no point of checking whether `b` is true or not. 
So that's why most of the programming languages implemented like that.
The same is true for all irrespective of data type.

Comment: Not quite; the number is only input once; say, in this case, I type in "0". It will go through the while loop, I change it to say "4", it goes on to the next thing. If I type "9" the first time, it will completely ignore the while loop and go on, and it SHOULD go through the while loop that first time with 9 or higher.

If I type 9 the first time, that doesn't fulfill the first condition of "num<1", so the condition isn't met, yet the program is skipping it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `AND` means both the condition should be true. As you have put `&&` condition inside `while` it became impossible for the compiler to get a `num` which is less than 1 as well as greater than 9.

For `AND` it always checks the first condition; if it's not satisfied it becomes lazy and doesn't check for subsequent conditions.

Solution:

```
while(num<1 || num>9)
```

Comment: Aah, I see what you and the first commenter were saying. I assume that's just for ints, because I've never had that happen to Strings before. How do I reformat it to register both conditions? That "||" won't work, will it? 'Cause if I type any number, it'll be accepted because any number meets at least one of those statements.

Comment: That depends on how you phrase your condition. You can easily say -`"num should be greater than 0 AND less than 9"` or `"number shouldn't be less than 0 OR greater than 9"`. Conditionals always behaves consistently among all datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet there, the expression:

```
(num < 1 && num > 9)
```

Will always evaluate to false, a number can not simultaneously be less than one and also greater than nine.

I think you want:

```
(num > 0 && num < 9)
```

EDIT: Also, Helios is correct. expressions are evaluated left to right and in the case of a boolean AND (&&) if the first condition (on the left) is not satisfied, the second condition (on the right) will never be evaluated because the combined expression can never evaluate to anything but false.

Answer (score 0):

as your condition a given number has to be less than 1 **"and"** greater than 9, which will never be true.

For your scenario you need to use an **"or"** condition

`while(num<1 || num>9)`

Answer (score 0):

When you write `num<1 && num>9` it means you are trying to evaluate if the number is *less than 1 **AND** greater than 9*, but can you really input such number?

According to your requirement, you should check if provided number is *less than 1 **OR** greater than 9*. So it should be like:

```
while(num<1 || num>9){
```

Logical operators, `&&` and `||`, also use shortcut approach while evaluating condition. In `cond1 && con2`, if first condition `cond1` is `false` then there is no point in evaluating second condition ie `cond2`. Similarly in `cond1 && con2`, if `cond1` is `true`, `cond2` will not be evaluated as it's redundant.